# Xerox solid ink - a good all rounder or has limited use?

Tags: print-design

I want to move over to a Xerox solid Ink printer but have concerns about its suitability for some applications.

For example will the solid ink repel adhesives (e.g. window stickers) or crack with too much handling/movement (e.g. kids stickers)?

Would appreciate any feedback and also recommendations for specialised  adhesives/papers/sticker.

Comment: Hi BeckPerth, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your question. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!

Answer (score 1):

I looked in some forums and Xerox's website and it seems that solid ink printing in its' earliest form had some durability concerns, but Xerox [claims to have improved](http://www.office.xerox.com/solid-ink/solid-ink-faq/enus.html).

One of their other claims is that solid ink's quality is virtually paper-independent, which makes sense to me: laser and inkjet printers have some dependence on paper's porous nature, whereas solid ink doesn't go as deep into the paper, so images will hypothetically look sharper.

Left: color inkjet, Right: solid ink (via Xerox)

[image: Solid ink vs color laser macro view]